# Tell anonymous users the reason "Improve this answer" link is hidden if there's already an edit in the queue

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, anonymous

As you can see, there is a link to improve the question. There are also links to improve all the other answers.

But where <s>is</s> *was* the link to edit this [answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/13305)?

> [image]

---

OK, animuson figured it out; [an edit](https://politics.stackexchange.com/revisions/13305/2) was pending. (The easiest way to replicate this behavior is to have access to a review queue and open up the answer in incognito mode.)

Since nobody has posted an answer, I'm changing this to a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Once upon a time, the edit button would disappear for users under 2k when edits were pending. This [was changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/81681/revisions) so that the button was grey:

> [image]

The hover text clarifies:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

The old behavior is similar to what happens to answers viewed by anonymous users, but not questions.

Curiously enough, "improve this question" becomes "edit" when a question edit is pending, instead of disappearing (I took this pic in incognito, of course):

> [image]

Clicking on edit lets me edit the other user's suggested edit, although I'm not sure the mechanics at play exactly (is this a bug?).

---

**Anonymous users should either be told why they can't edit an answer, or the behavior should match that of questions.**

Comment: There's already another suggested edit pending for the answer.

Comment: This was super-confusing to me when I edited posts here anonymously.