# Missing "improve question" link

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Last week, I tried to suggest an edit for a question on a Stack Exchange site on which I did not have an account. I say "tried," because the button for "improve this question" was missing. I [reported the issue on that site's meta](https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com/q/239/8723), but I don't see that anything happened.

Today, it happened again. And now I have pictures:

[image: a question from the History site, with the area of the missing "improve this question" link circled]

[Why did only the English adopt, evolve and use the longbow en masse in war?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/35769)

For comparison, this is what you're supposed to see.

[image: A question with the "improve this question" link circled]

[What is the idea behind the touch move rule?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/16814)

However, not every question on History is affected:

[image: A different History question, with the link present]

[Pre-columbus, what tools did Native Americans use to shave their heads and faces?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/35766)

I'm using Chrome 56 and Windows 10 (no available updates for either). The issue persisted when I opened the page in incognito mode, and also when I opened it in Firefox.

This is only the second time I've noticed it, but this bug seems to like beta sites.

---

PS Will someone with a History account and sufficient rep *please* fix the their/there error in the first sentence of the last paragraph? Thanks.

Comment: I noticed this before too. Here's the [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286866/323179).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had an account you would see that the "edit" link is disabled and the tooltip reads:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

So, basically, there's already a suggested edit (probably the thing you wanted to fix) and until that's processed you can't suggest another edit. I'd approve the edit, but I don't have enough rep on the site to do reviews.